# Как на практике используются читатели и преобразователи Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

В каких случаях используются читатели и преобразователи ? Если можно пример применения на практике. Просто не совсем понимаю зачем они.

Comment: Подробнее ? ты про $cast ? или ты про сеттеры и геттеры ?

Answer (score 0):

Во один пример использования на практике.
В таблице товаров есть два поля:

`weight_type - может иметь два значения: 0 - вес в килограммах и 1 - вес в граммах`

`weight - само значение веса в соответствующих weight_type единицах`

Допустим, в списке товаров необходимо выводить вес товара в килограммах. Вместо того, чтобы нагромождать шаблон логическим конструкциями @if @else @endif, создаем читателя:

```
public function getWeightInKgAttribute() {
    if ($this->weight_type == 1) {
        return $this->weight / 1000;
    }
    return $this->weight;
}
```

И теперь в шаблоне можно вес в килограммах выводить следующим образом:

```
{{ $good->weight_in_kg }}
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-mutators).